# Firebase - How to reply to support case?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have opened a user case in Firebase and received an email reply of it, but I can't find how am I supposed to reply to it. Should I just reply to that email, or there is some kind of dashboard where I can reply to it?

Comment: The automated email? You don't need to reply to that. Once someone from the Firebase team replies, you can then reply to that email for additional queries.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I was referring to the reply from the team. So I just have to answer to it ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you report something to Firebase Support, a case is open for you. So when you see an email that starts with `RE: Case 10199...`, then you can simply reply to it right from the browser or mobile app.

Comment: Hey there. Can I help you with other information?